# How to avoid "The instance of entity type 'xx' cannot be tracked" exception in ASP.NET Core & EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, .net-7.0, change-tracking

I'm encountering an issue in my ASP.NET Core application with Entity Framework Core where I repeatedly get the following response:

> The instance of entity type 'Airline' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{CarrierCode: DY}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

This occurs during the second iteration of a foreach loop in the `AddBaggage()` method in my `PassengerController` on the following line of code:

```
await _baggageRepository.AddAsync(newBaggage);
```

Here's the method:

```cs
[HttpPost("{id}/flight/{flightId}/add-baggage")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Baggage>> AddBaggage(Guid id, int flightId,
            [FromBody] List<AddBaggageModel> addBaggageModels)
{
    var passenger = await _passengerRepository.GetPassengerByIdAsync(id);
    var selectedFlight = await _flightRepository.GetFlightByIdAsync(flightId);
    var destination = await _destinationRepository.GetDestinationByCriteriaAsync(f =>
    f.IATAAirportCode == addBaggageModels.FirstOrDefault().FinalDestination);            

    var baggageList = new List<Baggage>();

    foreach (var baggageModel in addBaggageModels)
    {
        var newBaggage = new Baggage
                {
                    PassengerId = passenger.Id,
                    Weight = baggageModel.Weight,
                    DestinationId = destination.IATAAirportCode
                };

        //...some code
    
        else if (baggageModel.TagType == TagTypeEnum.System)
        {
            var number = _baggageRepository.GetNextSequenceValue("BaggageTagsSequence");
            var baggageTag = new BaggageTag(selectedFlight.ScheduledFlight.Airline, number);
            newBaggage.BaggageTag = baggageTag;
        }

        await _baggageRepository.AddAsync(newBaggage); // An exception is thrown here, on the second iteration, when we attempt to assign a reference to the same object/instance of Airline as in the first iteration in the constructor parameter.            
                
        baggageList.Add(newBaggage);

        var orderedFlights = passenger.Flights
                    .Where(f => f.Flight.DepartureDateTime >= selectedFlight.DepartureDateTime)
                    .OrderBy(f => f.Flight.DepartureDateTime)
                    .ToList();

        foreach (var connectingFlight in orderedFlights)
        {
            //...some code

            FlightBaggage flightBaggage = new FlightBaggage
                    {
                        Flight = connectingFlight.Flight,
                        Baggage = newBaggage,
                        BaggageType = baggageType
                    };

            newBaggage.Flights.Add(flightBaggage);

            //...some code
        }
    }

    await _baggageRepository.UpdateAsync(baggageList.ToArray());

    return Ok();
}
```

Here is also one of the `BaggageTag` constructors:

```cs
        public BaggageTag(Airline? airline, int number)
        {
            Airline = airline;
            LeadingDigit = 0;
            Number = number;
            TagNumber = _GetBaggageTagNumber();
            TagType = TagTypeEnum.System;
        }
```

And I also have the following code in my `PassengerRepository` and `FlightRepository`:

```cs
        public async Task<Flight> GetFlightByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var CACHE_KEY = $"Flight_{id}";

            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CACHE_KEY, out Flight flight))
            {
                flight = await _context.Flights.AsNoTracking()
                                       .Include(_ => _.ScheduledFlight)
                                       .ThenInclude(_ => _.DestinationFrom)
                                       .Include(_ => _.ScheduledFlight)
                                       .ThenInclude(_ => _.DestinationTo)
                                       .Include(_ => _.ScheduledFlight)
                                       .ThenInclude(_ => _.Airline)
                                       .Include(_ => _.Aircraft)
                                       .ThenInclude(_ => _.AircraftType)
                                       .Include(_ => _.Boarding)
                                       .Include(_ => _.ListOfBookedPassengers)
                                       .ThenInclude(_ => _.Passenger)
                                       .Include(_ => _.ListOfCheckedBaggage)
                                       .ThenInclude(_ => _.Baggage)
                                       .Include(_ => _.Seats)
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(_ => _.Id == id);

                if (flight != null)
                {
                    _cache.Set(CACHE_KEY, flight, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
                    {
                        SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                    });
                }
            }

            return flight;
        }
```

```cs
        public async Task<Passenger> GetPassengerByIdAsync(Guid id)
        {
            return await _context.Passengers.AsNoTracking()
                .Include(_ => _.PNR)
                .Include(_ => _.FrequentFlyer)
                .Include(_ => _.TravelDocuments)
                .Include(_ => _.PassengerCheckedBags)
                    .ThenInclude(_ => _.BaggageTag)
                .Include(_ => _.PassengerCheckedBags)
                    .ThenInclude(_ => _.SpecialBag)
                .Include(_ => _.Flights)
                    .ThenInclude(_ => _.Flight)
                        .ThenInclude(_ => _.ScheduledFlight)
                            .ThenInclude(_ => _.Airline)
                .Include(_ => _.Comments)
                    .ThenInclude(_ => _.PredefinedComment)
                .Include(_ => _.AssignedSeats)
                .Include(_ => _.SpecialServiceRequests)
                    .ThenInclude(_ => _.SSRCode)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(_ => _.Id == id);
        }
```

I understand that the issue stems from the ChangeTracker attempting to attach an entity that is already being tracked in the context.

However, I'm unsure how to efficiently avoid this. I've read about detaching entities using

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached
```

but I'm unsure where to place this line of code.

Should I add it in the `PassengerRepository`, `FlightRepository`, or `GenericRepository` within methods like `AddAsync()`, `UpdateAsync()` and `DeleteAsync()`?

Alternatively, should I override the `SaveChangesAsync()` method in my `AppDbContext` and include it there?

I'd appreciate any guidance or alternative solutions to resolve this issue effectively. Thank you for your help!

I've tried to remove all `AsNoTracking()` and `AsQueryable()` methods from my repositories, and everything worked perfectly. However, I initially added these methods to reduce memory overhead, and since then, I've been experiencing this problem.

Comment: You have given us pages of code but no indication where the error is happening. Try to cut down your code and figure out which part is thrown the exception.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues come to mind but the main suspect is that your repository methods are fetching data using `AsNoTracking()` (I.e. selectedFlight.ScheduledFlight.Airline) yet you are trying to associate these to a new instance of this booking and associated properties. When loading entities to be associated you do not want to use `AsNoTracking()` as this will return a fresh, and detached instance of entities when the `DbContext` may already be tracking other instances. This can result in errors like what you are seeing, or cases where you get exceptions due to index constraints or it inserts a duplicate record with a new ID. (it attempts to insert an associated untracked instance) Removing the `AsNoTracking()` in the fetching queries will likely resolve the issue.

This is one reason I do not recommend using Repository pattern like this because every call via the repository is a separate concern for that repository method. Some calls may want related data, some may not need it. Loading everything can be expensive so a "quick fix" might be to tack on an `AsNoTracking()` to improve performance, but that leads to unexpected problems where other code like updates like this would expect to be dealing with tracked references. If code uses the in-build repository pattern (DbSet) then consumers can better manage what related data to include and optimize `AsNoTracking()` for read-only operations.

Comment: Perhaps the Unit of Work pattern could help? I know that DbSet itself is a repository and DbContext is a Unit of Work, and these patterns are just another layer built on top of the built-in features of Entity Framework. But if I were to stick with the current model, could UoW be the solution? I've seen many different versions of this pattern, so I would still need to choose one that fits my project best.

Comment: As a means to avoid situations where you default to `AsNoTracking`? Possibly. As an alternative solution to still use non-tracking queries? No.  Especially when dealing with Dependency Injected, lifetime scoped DbContext instances. The root of the problem is that if you are going to associate existing entities previously read, those entities need to be tracked by the DbContext, and the same instances that the DbContext might be tracking.